# If $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ is a basis and $f$ is an injective morphism, show that $\{f(v_1), f(v_2), ..., f(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, morphism

Let $V_1$, $V_2$ be two $K$-vector spaces with $dim_K V_1 = dim_K V_2 = n$, $f:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ a morphism and $B = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ a basis for $V_1$.

Now consider the set $T = \{f(v_1), f(v_2), ..., f(v_n)\}$.

Is there a way to show that if $f$ is injective, then $T$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Yes there is. Do you know how to verify that a set of vectors is linearly independent?

Comment: By showing that the only linear combination of those vectors, that gives the zero vector, has all the scalars equal to zero? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: That's correct. So if I call the scalars $a_1, \dots, a_n$, you want to show that if $a_1f(v_1) + \dots + a_nf(v_n) = 0$, then $a_1 = \dots = a_n = 0$. Can you rewrite the expression $a_1f(v_1) + \dots + a_nf(v_n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Since $f$ is injective, the kernel of $f$ is $\{0\}$ (i.e., the only vector from $V_{1}$ being mapped to the $0$ vector in $V_{2}$ is the $0$ vector -- can you prove this?).

**Hint 2:**  $a_{1}f(v_{1}) + \dots + a_{n}f(v_{n}) = f(a_{1}v_{1} + \dots + a_{n}v_{n})$.

From hint 2, if the LHS $= 0$, what does that tell us about $a_{1}v_{1} + \dots + a_{n}v_{n}$?  What does this imply about $a_{1}, \dots, a_{n}$?

Comment: You are right, i didn't really understood the big picture of what a morphism is, and the concrete information I used was from Group theory... where $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ is enough, because that's the structure of a group.

Comment: It tells us that $\alpha_1 v_1 + ... + \alpha_n v_n = 0$, and because we know $v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent, it implies that $\alpha_1 = ... = \alpha_n = 0$.